# Specify title (header) for wdDialogFileOpen

Tags: vba, ms-word

I couldn't find method's name for specifying the title (header, caption) of the dialog box for wdDialogFileOpen in the Word object model (Visual basic for application).

The default title is "Open Document". Can you tell me what is the correct method?

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
 .Name = "C:\" 'default path
 .Title = "Choose a document to work with" 'this one is incorrect, because Title method does not exist. 
 .Show
End With
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Customizing-Word/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists-word

Comment: You can't set a new title for built-in dialogs. You'll have to write your own userform to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating an Excel object and calling a dialog box in it

```
Function ShowFileDialogResult()
    Dim oFD As Object
    Set oFD = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With oFD.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Choose a document to work with"
     End With
oFD.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: There is no need to use Excel to access the generic FileDialog. It is also available in Word. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.filedialog